# Bubble Sort Array with unknown length (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays

This is Java through my university so there are some components in here that you may not know.  Do not pay attention for them because they are not the problem.

My compiler made me initialize my array to null.  I then try to run the rest of my program and it said that it is supposed to work with an array that has actual values in it.  My question is how should I go about doing this?

```
private static String[] alphabetSort(Map<String, Integer> mapWord) {

    String[] ordered = null;

    Map<String, Integer> copy = mapWord;

    for (int i = 0; i < copy.size(); i++) {
        Map.Pair<String, Integer> pair = copy.removeAny();
        String key = pair.key();
        ordered[i] = key;
    }

    boolean flag = true;
    String temp;

    while (flag) {

        flag = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < ordered.length; j++) {

            String test1 = ordered[j];
            String test2 = ordered[j + 1];

            if (test1.compareTo(test2) < 0) {
                temp = ordered[j];
                ordered[j] = ordered[j + 1];
                ordered[j + 1] = temp;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return ordered;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to explain the circumstances behind  _"My compiler made me initialize my array to null."_ What did you have before?

Comment: You can't sort data if you don't know where it starts and stops. Code that you post here should not contain irrelevancies. Your question doesn't make sense, or meet the standards required here.

Comment: Did they rewrite the Java language for your University? When you have an error in your code, never assume that part of the code is unflawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays have **fixed-size**. You have to pick a size when you're creating it.

Try:

```
String[] ordered = new String[mapWord.size()];
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I haven't had much experience with arrays.  And thank you for not being an ass about answering the question.

Comment: @BrandonMinner I think the reason others were not friendly is that you didn't state the problem you were having very well. Fortunately I happened to see the problem in your code, but most of the time it's difficult to help debug a problem without a clear problem statement. See the [help/on-topic] for more information.